# Backward navigation from notification activity

Tags: android

For creating simple notification I'm using this code from documentation. Activity that is open when notification is clicked is transparent, so when is open is always home screen for background (This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of your application to the Home screen.), but that is't ok if some other app is open when notification is clicked. I want that back button from notification activity leads to previous open app not to home screen.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
        .setContentTitle("My notification")
        .setContentText("Hello World!");
// Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);

// The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
// started Activity.
// This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
// your application to the Home screen.
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
// Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
stackBuilder.addParentStack(ResultActivity.class);
// Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
        stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
            0,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        );
mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
// mId allows you to update the notification later on.
mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you mean that back button should get you out of your app instead of getting to home page when user clicked the notification while in other app, right ?

Comment: Yes. And also app that is open when notification is clicked should stay visible through transparent layout of activity that is open when notification is clicked.

Comment: If your project is small, can you send me your project zip here by uploading it to dropbox ? I will do the necessary changes on the project itself and send you back

Comment: Project is little bigger, so i will try to change it myself. I got one new idea what can i do when was reading your comment. If nothing works i will create one smaller project and let you know.